Will a .NET 8.0 application that references a NuGet package (that targets .NET 6.0) load the .NET 6.0 runtime and run the package on .NET 6.0?
Let's say I have an ASP.NET Core Web API running on IIS server. That application InternetResourceAPI has a direct dependency on a NuGet package called ResourceFetcher, which targets the .NET 6.0 runtime, and InternetResourceAPI targets the .NET 8.0 runtime.
When I build the InternetResourceAPI and host it on my IIS server, will the code in ResourceFetcher expect to run on the .NET 6.0 runtime, if it is installed and present in the hosting bundle?
What about with references of references?
InternetResourceAPI (.NET 8.0 application) -> ResourceFetcher2 (.NET 8.0 NuGet package) -> SomeDependency (.NET 6.0 NuGet package)
Would the code in SomeDependency run on the .NET 6.0 .dll (in my hosted environment) when it gets called?

It depends. Just like what we know that .Net 6 will end of life 2 month later and the current latest long-time-support version is .Net 8. Then do we need to uninstall .Net 6 after installing .Net 8? We can see from this section that NET runtime updates are compatible within a major version band such as 7.x and 6.x. newer releases of the .NET SDK generally maintain the ability to build applications that target previous versions of the runtime in a compatible manner

But I do faced scenarios that some app coding with .Net 6 and only worked in .Net 6, when .Net 6 runtime uninstalled, the application can't run well. So that my idea is that you can test ahead, I'm afraid it will run will .net 8

The short answer is your application will run .NET8.0 runtime.
TLDR
The application will use whichever .NET runtime it is targeting. Any dependent projects or packages (that aren't self contained) will use the runtime that the application loads.
Proof
You can test this for yourself by doing the following

Create a test project that targets net8.0
Add a dependent project that targets net6.0
Publish the application to a folder as Self-Contained
Inspect the dlls that were published.

Because the application is self-contained, it'll include the dlls for the .net runtime. If you inspect the dlls, like System.Runtime.dll or Microsoft.AspNetCore.dll, you'll find comments about net8 or .NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0. You won't find comments about net6
Documentation
I haven't found a word-for-word documentation from Microsoft on this. The best I can find is a combination of two rules

.NET runtimes are backwards compatible, so .NET8 can run projects that are targeting .NET6
The application runs using the framework that it targets.

The closest sentence is here.
It says
the .NET 8 SDK includes the .NET 8 runtime, which is an implementation of the net8.0 target framework. The .NET 8 SDK supports net7.0, net6.0, and net5.0, but not net9.0 (or higher). You install the .NET 9 SDK to build for net9.0.
IE If you want to build for a target runtime, target that runtime. Anything that uses a lower runtime will still be supported (if the target framework supports the lower framework), but will use the latest runtime.
You may wonder - as I did- "what if a dependent package is referencing a higher runtime then my application?" If that happens, the application won't build because it does not support the runtime that a dependency is trying to load.
